# Getting the Python PMW module?

Tags: python

I got a game which uses PMW in its code and I wanted to know is that already installed with Python, or does it come separate? Whre can I get it from so I could get this game running?

I  have difficulties opening it as it requires PMW.

Comment: Are you saying you need it and don't have it?  Doesn't that answer your question?  It's not part of Python if you don't have it.

Comment: -1: "thanks found the problem" with no further explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Pmw is a toolkit for building
>   high-level compound widgets in Python
>   using the Tkinter module.

It's not a standard library, you need to get it [from the project homepage](http://pmw.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: ive tried installing it and it doesnt work

Comment: Can you detail the errors you get? "doesn't work" is not too descriptive.

Answer (score 2):

http://opensourcejavaphp.net/python/pykeylogger/Pmw/Pmw.py.html
in this page you can copy/paste the codes and save as a py file next put it beside your script and execute it!
se vi bezonus mi en esperanto parolus!!